# How to use current website cookie information in a new marketing cloud implementation

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, website-integration, cookies, e-commerce

We are facing similar issue with several potential customers, when going through a Salesforce Marketing Cloud implementation project.

My question is how can we use/copy/migrate current cookie information the customers already have on their eCommerce systems into a new marketing cloud platform?

Thanks

Comment: What is your current system tracking? What vendor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Cloud tracks subscriber information for 6 months in its System [Data Views](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/). This time range is default (although you can engage support to extend this).

Unfortunately, these tables are read only and do not allow you to migrate / copy customer history into them. To by pass this, you would have to export your customer engagement data into Data Extensions within Marketing Cloud. This is particularly useful for [IP warm  up](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/email_deliverability/ip_address_warming_guide/) and to segment initially. As time goes on, the data from the old system becomes stale and you can rely solely on the info from SFMC.

For integration for website, you might want to look at [Predictive Web](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder/predictive_web/)

Comment: Thanks Data_Kid!
My intention is that users that are already known to my client (Identified in his e-commerce sys) will not have to Identify themselves again to the SF Marketing Cloud once it is implemented.
How can I achieve that? can I?
Thanks again